# Can we describe the number of something as： XX(noun) is more than xx (number)?

Tags: grammatical-number, numbers

In general, when we need to describe the number of something, we can say: over 100 people live here/ the number of people live here is over 100.
If my expressions are: people live here are over 100 / residents here are over 100 people, do they make sense?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

No.

"People who live here are over 100" will be unambiguously interpreted as "over 100 years old".

"The residents here are over 100 people" will be understood, but is not idiomatic.

"The residents here number 100" is possible, but I think many people would find it a bit formal for everyday speech.

Your first two expressions are the normal ones (except that you need "who" in the second one)